# Reference error in MATLAB (Undefined function or variable)

Tags: matlab

`[Rv,Rh]=Ref(theta,Er);`

Unrecognized function or variable for 'Ref'

**What function or method to make a correct reference?**

```
freq=2.0;
lamda=0.3/freq;
k=2*pi/lamda;
d=0:0.1:100;
Pt=0.0;
Gt=0.0;Gr=0.0;
zt=3.0;zr=1.5;
Er=5.0-1j*60*0.0005*lamda;
E0=1;

d0=sqrt(d.^2+(zt-zr)^2); 
d1=sqrt(d.^2+(zt+zr)^2); 

theta=acos((zt+zr)./d1); 
[Rv,Rh]=Ref(theta,Er); 

Ed=E0*(lamda/4/pi./d0); 
Egv=E0*(lamda/4/pi./d1).*Rv.*exp(-1j*k*(d1-d0)); 

Erec_v=Ed+Egv; 
L_v=-20*log10(abs(Erec_v));  
Prec_v=Pt+Gt+Gr-L_v; 

plot(d,Prec_v,'-b') 
grid 
axis([0 100 -90 -30]) 
legend('V-pol.') 
xlabel('Distance d (m)') 
ylabel('Received Power (dBm)') 
title('Distance Characteristics of 2 path model')
```

Comment: Have you defined a function named `Ref` and put it in a file named `Ref.m` on your Matlab path? That's how you define functions in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, the program was successful.

Comment: Yay! Glad I could be helpful.